# C++ - Program censors words specified in a vector

Tags: c++, nested-loops

My program is supposed to compare words entered to a vector of censored words; any words that should be censored print "BLEEP" instead of the word. However, I am having the issue that my nested for loop is comparing the entered word to the first censored word in the vector, then displaying something, comparing to the second, displaying, and so on and so forth, rather than comparing the word to the whole vector before displaying something, then moving on to the next entered word. How can I fix this loop?

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> censored = {"Rabbit", "Food", "Dog", "Monkey", "Zebra", "Kiwi"};         //Censored words

    cout << "Please enter words followed by a space. Ctrl+Z when you're done.\n";
    vector<string> words;
    for (string entry; cin >> entry;)                                   //Reads words separated by a space
        words.push_back(entry);                                                             //Puts words into vector words

    for (int w = 0; w < words.size(); w++) //Checks a word through censored vector before going to next word
        for (int c=0; c < censored.size(); c++)
            if (words[w] == censored[c])
                cout << "\nBLEEP";
            else
                cout << "\n" << words[w];

    keep_window_open();
}
```

Comment: Free clue: you can only print anything after your code checked each word against ***every*** word in the censored list. Since this code prints something ***inside the loop*** that compares each word against each word in the censored list, it must be obviously wrong. Rethink your logic, and whatever else you come up with, if anything gets printed inside the inner loop then it can't be right. If necessary, [schedule an emergency appointment with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: I realize this might be an assignment with restrictions on implementation, but if not the code would be easier to read and more directly express intent if you used `std::find`.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find

Comment: Try stepping through the program execution with a debugger or even just pencil and paper.

Answer (score 1):

You have already find the problem, and can just implement it!

> I am having the issue that my nested for loop is comparing the entered
>   word to the first censored word in the vector, then displaying
>   something, comparing to the second, displaying, and so on and so forth

That's exactly the program,

```
for (int w = 0; w < words.size(); w++)        //  For each word
    for (int c=0; c < censored.size(); c++)   //  and each censored word
        if (words[w] == censored[c])          //  compare them ...
            cout << "\nBLEEP";
        else
            cout << "\n" << words[w];
```

And the purpose is that

> comparing the word to the whole vector before displaying something,
>   then moving on to the next entered word

So the codes may be changed to

```
for (int w = 0; w < words.size(); w++)        //  For each word
{
    bool in_censored = false;                 //  we will find whether the world is in censored vector.
    for (int c=0; c < censored.size(); c++)   //  For each censored word
        if (words[w] == censored[c])          //  compare
            in_censored = true;               //  if same, the result for the word is set.
    if (in_censored)                          //  If the word is in censored.
        cout << "\nBLEEP";                    //  ...
    else
        cout << "\n" << words[w];
}
```

Comment: You could add a `break` after setting `in_censored` to slightly speed up the code.